# How to create a wavy surface bounded by intersecting curves between another curves & planes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I want to create an illustration of a water wave tank with one end of tank bounded by a snaky (a.k.a. multi element) wave maker paddle.

Here is how the snaky wave maker look like physically

[image]

And here is the code to show the wavemaker -

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{-30}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [tdplot_main_coords,
        tank/.style={very thick,black},
        axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
        wmkedge/.style={thick,black},           
        wmksurf/.style={red, opacity=.5},]

%draw the axes
\draw[axis] (0,0,3) -- (12,0,3) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,3) -- (0,6,3) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,3) -- (0,0,5) node[anchor=west]{$z$};

%draw the top and bottom of the tank
\draw[tank] (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0) -- (10,5,0) -- (0,5,0) -- cycle;
\draw[tank] (0,0,3) -- (10,0,3) -- (10,5,3) -- (0,5,3) -- cycle;

%draw the edges of the tank
\draw[tank] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
\draw[tank] (0,5,0) -- (0,5,3);
\draw[tank] (10,0,0) -- (10,0,3);
\draw[tank] (10,5,0) -- (10,5,3);

%draw edges of wavemaker
\draw[wmkedge] (0,0,1) -- (0.5,0,2.8);
\draw[wmkedge] (0,5,1) -- (-0.5,5,2.8);
\draw[wmkedge] (0,0,1) -- (0,5,1);  
\draw[wmkedge] (0.5,0,2.8) .. controls (-0.25,1.7,2.8) and (0.25,3.5,2.8)  .. (-0.5,5,2.8);

%draw wave maker surface
\fill[wmksurf] (0,0,1) --(0.5,0,2.8) .. controls (-0.25,1.7,2.8) and (0.25,3.5,2.8)  .. (-0.5,5,2.8) -- (0,5,1) --cycle;
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: The tank now looks like this]

Now I want a wavy free surface of water also to be added to it. The free surface is bounded by the wave maker on one side of tank and then by walls at the far and lateral end of the tank.

I don't want the free surface to penetrate through the wave maker.

That is the patch plot of the free surface is bounded by the curves created by the intersection of horizontal planes and tank boundaries.

Comment: Like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411899/194703)?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat It is close. But what I want but my paddle is snake-type that is the across the width of the wave maker the profile is also changing. It is not flat.

Comment: I just tried to help. I am not sure how many understand what you want from your description, at least I do not. So I was hoping this would allow you to get some water wave and if you do not get quite what you want you have a more specific starting point.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I updated the question with a pic of a physical snake wave maker. I want to show the water surface. The water surface will follow the profile of the wave maker across the width of the tank.